# Predicate logic equivalence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

I have been reading this article about Tarski's undefinability theorem:

https://qubd.github.io/files/TarskiUndefinability.pdf

It has a very interesting section on page 4:
[image]
This does not really make sense to me. If $\varphi_n$ (a formula with the Godel's number $n$) is a formula with one free variable, then $\forall v_1 (v_1 = \overline{n}\rightarrow \varphi_n) $ seems to be an incorrect notation. It's because $\varphi_n$ is a formula with a free variable -> therefore, it cannot be neither true nor false, and therefore it cannot be a consequent in an implication. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I notice that they said that $ \phi _ n $ has $ v _ 1 $ as its only free variable.  Often, writers will suppress the free variables, so that $ \phi _ n $ means the entire expression with $ v _ 1 $ in it, and $ \phi _ n ( a ) $ means the result of substituting $ a $ for the free occurences of $ v _ 1 $ in this expression.  With this convention, $ \phi _ n $ is the same thing as $ \phi _ n ( v _ 1) $.  So the statement is $ \forall v _ 1 ( v _ 1 = \overline n \rightarrow \phi _ n ( v _ 1 ) ) $, which is indeed equivalent to $ \phi _ n ( \overline n ) $.

Comment: @TobyBartels I see now, thank you. The universal quantifier at the beginning of the expression basically talks about the free variable which is substituted $v_1 = \overline{n}$.